# Why is onsubmit="" so slow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I was using this first:

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate()">
    ...
    <input type="submit" id="submit-button"/>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function validate() {
    // many lines for a big validation with regex and so on...
    $('form').submit();
}
```

**I noticed, that this was loading very long, so I changed it to:**

HTML:

```
<form>
    ...
    <input type="submit" id="submit-button"/>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function validate() {
    // many lines for a big validation with regex and so on...
        $('form').submit();
    }

    $('#submit-button').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        validate();
});
```

**And the loading time was OK and about 100 times faster!**

Can someone give me a - hopefully - short answer to this?

Comment: You *don't* want to process validation when the button is clicked, because this isn't the only way to submit a form. Pressing "enter" within a text field will bypass your validation completely.

Comment: Remove the `validate();` function call from your click hander. Does the form still submit?

Comment: @Blazemonger I used to think like you, but after some testing it seems like pressing "Enter" on a text field does indeed trigger the submit button's click handler: http://jsfiddle.net/bYN2c/ (the behavior is consistent in Chrome/Firefox, can other users check whether this behavior is consistent in their browsers?), well, I'm only commenting for experimentation purposes, the proper way to handle form submissions is through a submit handler of course.

Comment: @Blazemonger no its not submitting

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Sadly, I can't test that in IE8 because jsFiddle doesn't support it.

Comment: @Blazemonger Oh that's no problem, let me downgrade from jQuery 2.x to 1.x and link the rendered result only: http://jsfiddle.net/bYN2c/1/show -- and yeah, it seems to fail in my IE8 as well, so better stick with the submit handler

Comment: ...and, yep... IE8 won't trigger the click handler. It's nice of modern browsers to trigger a click under these circumstances, but I don't think it's technically *correct* to do so, and I would never assume it.

Comment: @Blazemonger thanks for the testing help. `=]` Made me a bit intrigued whether this behavior was introduced in HTML5 or just a browser thing. Well nevertheless, the proper way to handle submissions is through a form submit handler as you've mentioned initially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the first example, you are firing a `submit` event inside the `submit` callback, then the call stack exceeds [[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqvGa/)].

The second example relies on a `click` event, so things *seem* to work, but you should better fire your HTTP call via ajax after validation.

Comment: i guess thats it... thanks for the short answer :) - makes sense

Comment: Very succinct. Wouldn't have thought of highlighting the issue in the first example with a Fiddle.

Comment: Ok so i went back now to the onsubmit="" handler and instead of form.submit(); I just return true; cant remember why I did something stupid ^^ first

Answer (score 0):

Your function is called `validate()`, but I don't see any validation, just a `submit` event. The thing is, the way you have it set-up is wrong.  `validate()` should be returning `true/false` so the form knows if it should continue or not.  So instead, your validate function should look more like this:

```
function validate() {
  //many lines for a big validation with regex and so on...
  if (val=='') { return false; }
  else { return true; }
}
```

Now your form will only submit when the `validate()` function returns `true`, otherwise, it will not continue.  This will fix your issue, so you are not looping out.

Comment: yeah you are right, this was part of the problem and is how to solve it... got it now ;) - what i want to read was more like the "why is it that slow" and moonwave99 already given the right answer for it. but thanks anyway